# Automation Stops reading properly in Pro Tools LE. 

Tags: automation, plugin, pro-tools, post-production, dialogue

I'm working on a feature film in Pro Tools 8 LE on my Macbook. There's a scene in where I'm automating a reverb plug-in on my dialog aux, due to the characters going in different rooms down a long hallway, in one single take. About halfway, my automation stops reading correctly and when I go back earlier in the scene after it stops reading, all of the parameters for the plug are all wonky. It's only until I go to a different point in the timeline or just relaunch the session, where everything is okay until it gets to the same point. What is causing this and what should I do?

Comment: have you actually looked at the automation lanes for your reverb plug-in at that point? if you haven't, it would be worth checking them to make sure the automation wasn't recorded that way.

Comment: The automation is supposed to read as a small room and it turns into a large one, even though the automation paths only go from small to medium. Once this change happens in the scene, all of the automation from before gets set to the large echo, that only goes back to my original automation once I either quit the session or dramatically go back and forth in the timeline. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shot in the dark, are you using D-Verb? I've ran into this many times and eventually just stopped using the plug because of it. It's a known bug that sadly seems to have been around a long time. I'm pretty sure it's switching either the algorithm or the size that screws things up.

Find another reverb you love and don't look back IMO.

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=306998
http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=200883

Comment: Thanks Luca! I'm looking into Valhalla Room from Valhalla DSP. It's pretty cheap and will be better suited for the time being. 